# What type of exception is (0)null?

Tags: java, exception, axis

I am using Apache Axis, and I am getting exception of type `(0)null`. Here is partial stack trace:

```
....
....
org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: (0)null
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.netsuite.webservices.platform_2012_1.NetSuiteBindingStub.upsertList(NetSuiteBindingStub.java:11841)
....
....
```

Following is what I see in HTTPSender source code.

```
....
AxisFault fault = new AxisFault("HTTP", "(" + returnCode + ")" + statusMessage, null, null);
....
throw fault;
....
```

Comment: Wow. That's a truly bizarre error. Time to look at the code for HTTPSender...

Comment: Can you just clarify whether this is 1.4 or 1.4.1? The latter was released just 6 months after the former. (Back in 2008... I'd urge an upgrade if possible :)

Comment: Aagh, Axis, not Axis2. Sorry, my mistake... So 2006, not 2008 :)

Comment: [Lines 685-689](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.axis/com.springsource.org.apache.axis/1.4.0/org/apache/axis/transport/http/HTTPSender.java#689) seem promising. No value is assigned to the integer so in combination with an undefined error message this should return `(0)null`.

Comment: Presumably someone threw `null` as an exception.

Comment: May help you: http://thejavablog.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/0null/

Comment: Is it throwing a `NullPointerException`? What is the exception that goes along with the message?

Comment: I am so sorry, I am not using axis 1.4. I am using Axis 2. Sorry for confusion. version is 1.6.2

Comment: @riship89 Are you sure? The FQN of `HTTPSender` on axis2 is `org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender`, which is not what I'm seeing in your stacktrace.

Comment: exception seems to be of type AxisFault.

Comment: I am so sorry about this, I am using axis not axis2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the exception is of type `AxisFault`, but it looks like `statusMessage` is `null`. [Line 444](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.axis/com.springsource.org.apache.axis/1.4.0/org/apache/axis/transport/http/HTTPSender.java#744) is:

```
AxisFault fault = new AxisFault("HTTP", "(" + returnCode + ")" + statusMessage, null, null);
```

The `(0)null` part comes from `"(" + returnCode + ")" + statusMessage`. `statusMessage` itself is assigned in [line 742](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.axis/com.springsource.org.apache.axis/1.4.0/org/apache/axis/transport/http/HTTPSender.java#742):

```
String statusMessage = msgContext.getStrProp(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_STATUS_MESSAGE);
```

`returnCode` is set to `0` early on in the method. The next few statements should set it to its correct value:

```
Integer rc = (Integer) msgContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_STATUS_CODE);
if (rc != null) {
    returnCode = rc.intValue();
} else {
    // No return code?? Should have one by now.
}
```

After this, the `if` block and none of the `else if` blocks get executed since the return code is `0` (because `rc` is `null`). It finally lands up in the `else` block where it generates the `AxisFault` exception.

You will notice that the `statusMessage` itself is `null`. The only place I can see it setting this property is on [line 641](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.axis/com.springsource.org.apache.axis/1.4.0/org/apache/axis/transport/http/HTTPSender.java#641), which is the `readHeadersFromSocket` method.

The only way the status message and the return code *will not* be set is if they are already `null`, *or if* there is an error earlier on in the method, which causes control to break out of the `for` loop that starts on [line 581](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.axis/com.springsource.org.apache.axis/1.4.0/org/apache/axis/transport/http/HTTPSender.java#581). Of particular interest are [line 585](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.axis/com.springsource.org.apache.axis/1.4.0/org/apache/axis/transport/http/HTTPSender.java#585) and [line 598](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.axis/com.springsource.org.apache.axis/1.4.0/org/apache/axis/transport/http/HTTPSender.java#585), both of which are `if` statements that will `break` out of the loop if their test-condition is true. One of these statements checks to see if the value of `inp.read()` is `-1` (which means that the end of the stream has been reached), the other checks to see if the length of what was read in is `0`. These conditions can hold true if there is a network error (i.e., nothing read from the socket) or if nothing was returned from the server (zero-length data). So if any of these conditions are true, control breaks out of the loop. Eventually, `readFromSocket` will throw the exception since it wasn't able to get a return code. But because the failure happened before it could even set an error message, you get a `null` error message.

**tl; dr;** There is probably some sort of network/read error.

Comment: Thanks for elaborate explanation. Appreciate it.